# Another exception was thrown: PersistedTransform: is in an unexpected state. Another exception was thrown: PersistedOffset: is in an unexpected state

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, gridview

When I scroll to end of grid view and try to scroll back I get this error . the entire page gets hanged. I am testing on chrome web.
below is code

take this link as URL to get all json - https://360softwares.in/assignments/sniper/rexello_mobile/rexello_get_seriesdata_api/lightduty_series.php

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../global_function/custom_app_bar.dart';
import '../view_by_screen/model/series_products.dart';
import '../view_by_screen/view_by_screen.dart';
import 'components/series_cards.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//temp delete or comment later
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// class DeviceSize {
//   static late double height;
//   static late double width;
//   static double figmascreensizeWidth = 390;
//   static double figmascreensizeHeight = 844;

//   static void setScreenSize(BuildContext context) {
//     height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
//     print(height);
//     width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
//     // print(width);
//   }
// }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SeriesScreen(
        getUrl: 'null',
      ),
    );
  }
}

//
// starts below
//
class SeriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SeriesScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.getUrl,
  });

  final String getUrl;

  @override
  State<SeriesScreen> createState() => _SeriesScreenState();
}

class _SeriesScreenState extends State<SeriesScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool dataFetched = false;

  List<User> userList = [];

  String get getUrl => widget.getUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  //
  // function to fetch data on init from url
  //
  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(getUrl));
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        dynamic jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

        if (jsonData is List) {
          userList = jsonData
              .map(
                (item) => User(
                  id: (item['id']),
                  name: item['series_name'],
                  image: item['series_image'],
                  weight: item['series_capacity'],
                ),
              )
              .toList();
        } else if (jsonData is Map) {
          userList.add(
            User(
              id: (jsonData['id']),
              name: jsonData['series_name'],
              image: jsonData['series_image'],
              weight: jsonData['series_capacity'],
            ),
          );
        }

        setState(() {
          dataFetched = true;
        });
      } else {
        print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DeviceSize.setScreenSize(context);

    if (!dataFetched) {
      // Show loading indicator or any other UI while data is being fetched
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            //
            // custom appbar
            //
            CustomAppBar(
              scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
              title: "Series Screen",
            ),
            //
            // content with grid list
            //
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal:
                      DeviceSize.width * (28 / DeviceSize.figmascreensizeWidth),
                ),
                // implement GridView.builder
                child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.78,
                        crossAxisSpacing: DeviceSize.width *
                            (30 / DeviceSize.figmascreensizeWidth),
                        mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                    itemCount: userList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                      User user = userList[index];
                      return SeriesCards(
                          heroId: index,
                          title: user.name,
                          weight: user.weight,
                          image:
                              "https://rexello.com/images/castors/${user.image}");
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting to easily scroll back from the end of list but UI gets hanged. I am intermediate in flutter any help will be great. It works fine on mobile but on web for testing its get stuck.